# Is the logic wrong? Calculating percentage of salary to save to pay for downpayment

Tags: python, python-3.x

Problem is using bisection search to find the portion of salary to save in 3 years to pay for down payment. Unable to achieve the test cases with my code. Doesn't seem like there's any problem with my code?

1. semi-annual pay raise is 0.07
2. annual return of 0.04 from investments
3. down payment is 0.25 of the cost of house
4. cost of house is $1M
5. duration to save is 36 months
6. savings is to be within $100 of down payment

test cases to be met:

1. test case 1

   - starting salary: 150000
   - savings rate: 0.4411
   - steps taken: 12
2. test case 2

   - starting salary: 300000
   - savings rate: 0.2206
   - steps taken: 9
3. test case 3

   - starting salary: 10000
   - not possible to pay down payment in three years

the results which I obtained are as follows

1. test case 1

   - starting salary: 150000
   - savings rate: 0.1295
   - steps taken: 13
2. test case 2

   - starting salary: 300000
   - savings rate: 0.0647
   - steps taken: 14
3. test case 3

   - starting salary: 10000
   - not possible to pay down payment in three years

```py
annual_salary = int(input("Enter your annual salary: "))
the_annual_salary = annual_salary
total_cost = 1000000
semi_annual_raise = 0.07
portion_down_payment = 0.25
r = 0.04
num_months = 36
num_steps = 0

high = 10000
low = 0
guess = (high+low) / 2
current_savings = 0

while abs(current_savings - (portion_down_payment * total_cost)) > 100:
    current_savings = 0
    annual_salary = the_annual_salary
    for i in range(num_months):
        current_savings +=  current_savings * r/12
        current_savings += annual_salary * (guess/10000) /12
        if num_months % 6 == 0:
            annual_salary += semi_annual_raise * annual_salary

    if current_savings < portion_down_payment * total_cost:
        low = guess
        if guess == 10000:
            break

    elif current_savings > portion_down_payment * total_cost:
        high = guess        

    num_steps += 1
    guess = (high+low) / 2       


if (guess == 10000) and (current_savings < portion_down_payment * total_cost + 100):
    print("It is not possible to pay for the down payment in 36 months")
else:
    print("Percent of salary to save is", guess/10000)
    print("Number of steps taken:", num_steps)
```

Comment: Do you mean to say `binary search`?

Answer (score 0):

oh i found the problem... =.=

in the if statement, should replace num_months by i, since i is the temporary variable used in the loop..

```py
for i in range(num_months):
    current_savings +=  current_savings * r/12
    current_savings += annual_salary * (guess/10000) /12
    if i % 6 == 0:
        annual_salary += semi_annual_raise * annual_salary
```

results obtained

1. test case 1

   - starting salary: 150000
   - savings rate: 0.4169
   - steps taken: 12
2. test case 2

   - starting salary: 300000
   - savings rate: 0.2084
   - steps taken: 13
3. test case 3

   - starting salary: 10000
   - not possible to pay down payment in three years